# add related video to youtube short using API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've thoroughly explored the YouTube Data API documentation, but I'm still unclear on how to implement the related videos feature for YouTube Shorts.

[this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/14075157?hl=en) feature added recently

[here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) is the youtue api doc

any one done it before?

(this feature is fairly new possible there isn't any public api for it?)

I've read the youtbe api doc and couldn't find anything related to this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube data api is very old and has not been updated to support anything related to shorts.

What you want to do is not possible with the current api we have.